# Mocking an object in Jest that has a function that makes an Axios call

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an object in Jest that returns me property on an object that is a function call to Axios. I have this working using the Jest module default import syntax, but I can't get it working with `mockImplementation` and I need this so that I can change it each time.

```js
export const Users = {
  getUser: async id => {
    const result = await axios
      .get(`${user + id}.json`)
      .then(({ data }) => data);

    return result;
  },
};
```

In Jest I'm doing the following and this works fine, but I want to change it in each one of my tests, how can I do this? Can I use `mockImplementation`?

```js
import { usersApi } from '../apis/Users';

jest.mock('../apis/Users', () => ({
  users: {
    getUser: () =>
      Promise.resolve({
        id: 1,
        name: "Joe"
      }),
  },
}));
```

I have tried the following:

```js
usersApi.mockImplementation({
  usersApi: {
    getUser: () => Promise.resolve('I am a user'),
  },
});
```

But what I get is

> _usersApi.usersApi.mockImplementation is not a function

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, you can use `jest.spyOn` and `.mockResolvedValueOnce`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const user = 'user';

export const Users = {
  getUser: async id => {
    const result = await axios.get(`${user + id}.json`).then(({ data }) => data);
    return result;
  }
};
```

You can use `.mockResolvedValueOnce` method to mock value once in each test case:

```js
import { Users } from './';

describe('test suites', () => {
  let getUserSpyOn;
  beforeEach(() => {
    getUserSpyOn = jest.spyOn(Users, 'getUser');
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    getUserSpyOn.mockRestore();
  });
  it('t1', async () => {
    const userMocked = { id: 1, name: 'Joe' };
    getUserSpyOn.mockResolvedValueOnce(userMocked);
    const actualValue = await Users.getUser(1);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(userMocked);
  });
  it('t2', async () => {
    const userMocked = { id: 1, name: 'mrdulin' };
    getUserSpyOn.mockResolvedValueOnce(userMocked);
    const actualValue = await Users.getUser(1);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(userMocked);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57931751/index.spec.ts
  test suites
    ✓ t1 (9ms)
    ✓ t2 (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.741s, estimated 3s
```

Comment: That's awesome dude, thanks so much, can't believe I forgot about Spy!

Comment: @PaulAsmon Glad to help! BTW, use `jest.SpyOn()` is one way, you can also use `jest.fn()`

Comment: would it be possible to show how to do this with jest.fn(), considering that it's an object to begin with and we aren't creating a mock function?